# how to hide a link when the browser refresh using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem how can I remove the link when the browser refreshes it? 
Here's my code.

```
    //post cheer!!!!!!!
    $('.comment_likes').live("click",function(e){
        var id          = $(this).attr('rel');
        var url         = $(this).attr('href');
        var thisClass   = this;

        if(like2 == true){
        like2 = false;   

            setTimeout(function(){
                $.post(url,function(data){
                    $(thisClass).fadeOut('slow').fadeIn();
                    $(thisClass).removeClass('remove');
                    $(thisClass).addClass('add');

                    $('#boo_click_'+id).hide();
                    like2 = true;
                });       
            },500);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: could be wrong, but i think you'll either need to use a cookie or a php session to hold a variable to check on page load

Comment: How are you identifying the person who has previously 'liked' something? Is is acceptable to tie this to the session (so if they close their browser, then open it again, they'll be able to 'like' again) or are you authenticating users that you can tie this to?

Answer (score 1):

If your page is reloading, you lose any client-side information that gets set on refresh / reload, so you'll need to set a session variable or cookie when the link is clicked, set a javascript variable in the head if the session variable or cookie exists, and check for that variable on page load. If it exists, either don't display the link, or remove the link via jquery (best option is to have conditional code on the server side to determine if the link should be displayed or not - no need to add unnecessary DOM manipulation on page load).

Your other option is to refresh the content via AJAX instead, sans the link, which may actually be faster.